Redirection of Domain in Route 53 and AWS
I have help desk created in Zendesk, but the zendesk provided an URL with their domain ("example.zendesk.com"). I wanted to redirect this service with my domain name, so I added an Route 53 Record with CNAME which points to "example.zendesk.com".
I Created one record support.example.com ===> example.zendesk.com
But, few of my jobs were using www.support.example.com which was unidentified on Zendesk side.
I tried to create another record with www.support.example.com which points to example.zendesk.com (As CNAME), but it returned 1001 Status Code.
I Also, tried to add alias record where www.support.example.com will point support.example.com. Yet it returned 409 Status Code.
Any one has any idea how can I redirect the www.support.example.com to support.example.com with using AWS Services if possible rather than using any third party tools to redirect the domains.

Use S3 for your redirect https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/how-to-page-redirect.html

Thanks Tim, The S3 Redirect worked for me, I have used Cloudfront for SSL Certificates and Route 53.

I suggest you use S3 web hosting for your redirect.
I posted this so you can accept an answer to close the question.
